# How to position block element horizontally and center contained text

Tags: css, position

I would like to take a block element and position it near the right border of the parent element, while having the text inside the element centered. How do I go about this using CSS?

```
    <div class="A">
      some text - some text - some text - some text - some text - 
        <div class="B">
          some text
        <br/>
          some more text
        </div>
      some text - some text - some text - some text - some text
   </div>
```

The text inside div class="A" should be aligned left or justified, while the element div class="B" should be positioned to the right with a margin of, say, 30px, with the lines of text inside  centered.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And, what have you tried so far to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should post what you have tried.

Anyway, here's a way to do this using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

```css
.B {
  color: red;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right:30px;
}
.A {
   display:flex;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   flex-direction: column;
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
  <div class="A">
    some text - some text - some text - some text - some text -
    <div class="B">
      some text
      <br />
      some more text
    </div>
    some text - some text - some text - some text - some text
  </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to position an element relative to it's parent element, you should use absolute position on the child element and position it using top, bottom, right and left:

```
.A{
      width: 100px;
      height: 200px;
}
.B{
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      width: 50px;
      height: 5px;
}
```

And for aligning text inside an element you should use text-align:

```
text-align: center;
text-align: left;
text-align: right;
text-align: justify;
```